# Is there a way to restrict map markers to the area currently being displayed on a google map (using the goMap plugin)?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to programmatically change the zoom level and location of a map. Specifically, starting off showing the contiguous (48 states) U.S.A., I want to zoom into specific states. I use the goMap plugin (http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/). I know that this can be accomplished by "resetting" - removing the existing map setup parameters, such as zoom, location, and map type, and starting "fresh" with new values.

However, if I already have, for example, markers for the entire USA, and the new zoom level shows only Missouri, is there a way that I can restrict the markers that have to be redrawn during this "reset" process to ignore those that won't be visible on the map at its current projection (Missouri)?

IOW, why take the time to draw all the markers when only a small percentage of them will be seen?

I could write several methods, such as ShowAllMarkers(), ShowMissouriMarkers(), ShowCaliforniaMarkers(), etc., but I'm hoping there's a way to simply only draw on the visible surface.

Is this possible, or a pipe dream?

gomap googlemaps jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for would be implemented in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (which is the underlying API used by goMaps) by getting the visible bounds and only displaying the markers that are "contained" by it.

Go map gives you access to the native map object:

```
$.goMap.map
```

and the markers:

```
$.goMap.markers
```

so this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener($.goMap.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  var map = $.goMap.map;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var markers = $.goMap.markers;
  for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
     if (bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition()) {
        // show the marker
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
        // hide the marker
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
});
```